# How to avoid being played by a coworker?

Tags: work-environment, coworkers

One of my friends, a woman of about thirty, is trapped with a "player" in her workplace. Some context: The country is Iran, in their room they are 5 people and one guy is playing "catch and run" with her:

He tries to be emotionally engaged with her, and insists so much that she gives in. Then right at that moment, he pretends that nothing special is between them. Then he approaches again, and when she shows no interest, he tries new actions like chatting with another female coworker and laughing loudly, texting her etc.

At the moment, she admits she is emotionally engaged in this game, but she is willing to exit.

Now I know this kind of play, and my suggestion is to get out of it immediately, but what if she has to continue working with him?

Is there a name for this kind of action? How can she deal with that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to be a question that can be answered using interpersonal skills. Not only that, you cannot dictate how another person behaves. If you rework the question to be something like "How can I have a conversation with my friend about a potentially unhealthy relationship without upsetting her?" that is something that could be answered.